# When will my old page stop appearing on Google?

Tags: seo, google, domains, googlebot, blogger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Old pages still appearing in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14553/old-pages-still-appearing-in-google)

I recently bought a new address for my Blogger blog, from [yannbane.blogspot.com](http://yannbane.blogspot.com/) to [www.yannbane.com](http://www.yannbane.com/). However, [www.yannbane.com](http://www.yannbane.com/) addresses do not appear when they are searched for! Is this natural? How much time will it take for Google to update its index?

[yannbane.blogspot.com](http://yannbane.blogspot.com/) 301's to [www.yannbane.com](http://www.yannbane.com/). Both are added to my Webmaster Tools account, but it shows no data for [www.yannbane.com](http://www.yannbane.com/) (strangely). And, finally, is there something I could do to speed up the process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately no one can say you when Google will. According to my experience it can take a lot of time, also several months.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I'm getting yannbane.com in positions 2 and 3 in Google (UK and US) for the term "tautological cascade", and site: command reports 29 results for the whole domain. The only thing outranking you, in fact, is your own WordPress.com site. So the lack of data in GWT is something else. Google knows you've moved.

Comment: Oh wow, now I'm on the second place! My old WordPress.com site is still outranking me, though. Well, I guess that kinda answers my question.

Comment: You can buy a redirect from WordPress, if you want to fix that: [WP Site Redirect](http://en.support.wordpress.com/site-redirect/)

Comment: Nah... It sends out a 410, I bet it will be removed soon. Also, I didn't really want to buy anything from WordPress, I like Blogger more.